# Invoke-Item executes file locally

Tags: powershell, exe

I have a command

```
Invoke-Item \\remote_IP\share\setup.exe
```

That executes setup.exe on my local computer even though I specified "remote_IP" in the UNC path.

What is missing?

Comment: Are you trying to locally execute that Setup.exe that is located on the remote machine, or are you trying to execute it on the remote computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but it looks like you are trying to remotely execute an application. You don't want Invoke-Item for that, you want Invoke-Command which has the -ComputerName switch (along with other things to facilitate remote execution like accepting credentials).

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteIP -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\Path\To\Setup.exe'}
```

Or however you want to execute the file.

Comment: I tried `invoke-command -ComputerName remote_IP -scriptBlock {& 'C:\share\SETUP.exe'}` and I am trying to troubleshoot error **The WinRM client cannot process the request**

Comment: I am able to copy the executable file onto remoteIP, i.e. 'New-`PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\remoteIP\share -`Credential $credentials -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null', and `Copy-Item D:\SETUP.exe Z:\`  but why should there be a problem with executing this file via `invoke-command`?

Comment: Did you read the error? I'm guessing the IP isn't in your TrustedHosts or something. There's some stipulations to using it with an IP address. The process is MUCH simpler if you use a computer name.

Comment: There is a HUGE security difference between copying a file, and running an executable.

Comment: Still getting same error with computer name, _The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client 
computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts._

Comment: At this point it's an authentication issue. The remote computer doesn't know you, so it's not allowing you to run applications. Try tossing in `$creds = Get-credential` and then add `-credential $creds` to you Invoke-Command line. Adding the machine to your TrustedHosts may help as well (if you do in fact trust them).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60032/discussion-between-glowie-and-themadtechnician).

Answer (score 1):

UNC paths have the following form `\\remote_name\share_name\path`. In your case the share_name is missing.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention

Also UNC paths only allow you to access file remotely, not execute them on the remote computer. For excecuting a program remotely you need a special service or tool support: https://serverfault.com/questions/221064/running-remotely-an-app-from-a-shared-folder-with-psexec

From PowerScript, however, you could also use the invoke-command command (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx)

Comment: I tried `start-process -FilePath D:\pstools\PsExec.exe -ArgumentList "-u $username -p $password \\remote_IP -accepteula C:\share\SETUP.exe"` and nothing is executing on the remote_IP